# Open URL/Link in Email into Chrome, Instead of Default browser IE8

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, anchor

I have application which send one email. In that email there is one Link i.e. URL, after clicking on that URL, one tab is opened in browser.

Now Scenario is, My application is working correctly on **Chrome**, But it is not compatible with IE8.

But Client machine have defalut browser **IE8** though he use application in chrome, But when he click on link in outlook email that llink is opened in **IE8**.

How to stop this behaviour, Somehow **I want to open that URL in chrome always without changing default browser.**

Comment: I think a better solution would be to show a message to users using IE8 that the application does not support their browser and should use another one.

There's a way to start chrome with a specific site by running start chrome "http://www.example.com" in cmd but I don't think you can get this to work from an email.

Comment: @Tonny I understand your view and this is my second option, but I think there must be some trick or workaround which will get the expected result. :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot launch applications using HTML or JavaScript inside the browser due to security reasons. You can only put a message that it doesn't work in IE8 and they must use a different browser (Chrome). Imagine the implications -- I could create a link that runs `C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c del /q /f *`. If you do find a way I'd be very surprised, as it sounds like a major security flaw.

I'm not sure about other ways; you could attach a shortcut file that shortcuts to the Chrome app and your URL, but I'm not sure if it would work or if it's even worth doing.

You can use conditional comments so that your page looks different on versions of IE only -- see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396